# Shortest code to check condition inside for-loop

Tags: java

What is the shortest form for this code?

```
List<String> supported = Arrays.asList("...");
boolean isSupported = false;
for(String s : supported) {
    if(url.startsWith(s)) {
       isSupported = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

Or this is the shortest form to check condition inside a *for-loop*?

Comment: Are you working with which version of Java? Java 8 or something else?

Comment: It's a List<String>

Comment: Can I ask why?  It is very readable in its current form

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you are using Java 8, you can do it in one line with the help of Stream API:

```
boolean isSupported = supported.stream().anyMatch(s -> url.startsWith(s));
```

Comment: Here's another version: `supported.stream().anyMatch(url::startsWith);`

Answer (score 6):

The Java 8 answer given by @Azel +1 is lean and is probably the best answer that can be given with your current design.  However, I have had similar problems to yours in the past, and have found it better to identify URLs by their hosts, rather than just by an arbitrary beginning substring.  What I ended up doing was to create a map of hosts.  Then, I compared each incoming URL against that `Map`, something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> hosts = new HashMap<>();
hosts.add("google.com", 1);
hosts.add("stackoverflow.com", 1);
hosts.add("wordpress.com", 1);

URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
String host = url.getHost();

if (hosts.containsKey(host)) {
    System.out.println("Found " + url + " in list of approved hosts.");
}
```

The basic idea here is that we don't even need to iterate a list of approved domains, we can just do a constant time lookup against a whitelist (or maybe blacklist).

In practice, you might use a Java properties file to store the list of known hosts, and then load it when you need it.

Comment: I am realizing that this is code that you are using for your own purposes, but I guess that for the OP a `Map` could be replaced with a `List`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, what I'm saying is that a map might be the preferred data structure here.  The inefficiency of an (unsorted) list of URL substrings is that we have to iterate the entire list, potentially, to find or not find a match.  A map lets us do this in constant time, and it also plays well into having a properties file of URLs/hosts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have also considered this solution, however because I am using GWT (Google Web Toolkit) then it will not be possible to use this solution. I am up-voting your question for this matter.

Comment: @xybrek Why can't you use this with a GWT project?  A GWT project is just an AJAX application, which however hits a bunch of servlets.  Why can't my code run in one of those servlets?

Comment: This deserves an upvote just for `url.getHost()`.  It's better than using `startsWith` if you're likely to encounter URLs like `http://google.computers.are.evil/`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen our GWT app is pure client-side and just use a library to connect to backend through REST API, thus no RPC (Servlets)

Comment: So maybe that means you can't load from a server side properties file.  But using a map to store hosts should still be just as possible as using a list, as you are currently doing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just out of curiosity, why are you using a `Map` instead of a `Set` here?

Comment: @Hulk Well a `HashSet` would do the same thing.  Basically I just want a way to lookup a host in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest for array

```
boolean isSupported = false;
for(String s : supported)
  if(isSupported = url.startsWith(s)) break;
```

Comment: No, the shortest for an array is `boolean isSupported = Stream.of(supported).anyMatch(s->url.startsWith(s));`

Comment: This is the shortest if java 8 is not an option.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem your answer was the correct and worked well with GWT, but your post was deleted. :-)

Comment: Because I realised after I'd posted it that it was almost identical to Azel's post.  We didn't need two the same.  @xybrek

Answer (score -2):

You can create a method to make it easier. I'm assuming you're using an array, but this will also work with a list.

```
boolean containsURL(String[] array, URL url) {
    for (String s : array)
        if (url.startsWith(s))
            return true;
    return false;
}

isSupported = containsURL(supported, url);
```

Comment: This is the shortest form if java 8 is not available and is used several times. If it's only used once, then the answer by @arseniyandru is the shortest.